# published application on google play available only for user with a given url

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I have and application published to Google Play , yet as requested by the client , he want the application to only be available for user who receive the download URL through mail .

basically the application is a reminder and schedule tracker for sessions that will take place during an event .

is there any way to make the application available only to user that receive the URL, not listed publicly , on Google Play

Answer (score 3):

Either use the [Google Apps private channel](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en), or put your app in [beta mode](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) and only give event members access.

Comment: Thanks Rag , but the 1st option they have a message posted "We are deprecating the classic Admin console on February 3rd, 2014." , but i think moving the application to beta mode is a fine idea

Comment: @user3136854 That's just for the access interface. The feature will still exist, just be accessible differently.

Comment: Google Apps private channel is a great solution.

Comment: Raghav , ur right, i read that in a haste , i'll give it a try then , thanks Rag , Ewald

Comment: sadly i can't access the admin console , i get the " 
Sign into a different account to access Google Admin."